# Лирические размышления

Tags: егэ

Здравствуйте. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с понятием **лирическое размышление**. Я не вполне понимаю, что это такое. У меня есть задание (таблица), в котором нужно разобрать различные темы, которые могут встретиться в части **С** ЕГЭ. Например, тема "Проблема ложной цели в жизни". Нужно написать по ней лирическое размышление (подобрать цитаты, произведения художественной литературы и прочее). Но вот именно с лирическими размышлениями я никак не могу добиться чего-либо толковогою Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: А в чем конкретно нужна помощь? Вы не до конца понимаете, чего от Вас хотят, или интересует конктретно заданная тема?

Answer (score 1):

Вообще, лирическое размышление можно иначе назвать "эссе".

Answer (score 0):

1. Прил. к лирика в 1 и 2 знач. (лит.). Лирическая поэзия. Лирический поэт. Восторг лирический в себе я пробужу. Некрасов.

|| С элементом лирики (лит.). Лирическая поэма.

|| С преобладанием эмоционально-субъективных элементов (преимущ. о музыкальных произведениях).

2. Повышенно-эмоциональный, проникнутый лирикой (в 3 знач.). Лирическое настроение. Лирические излияния.
3. Мягко-певучий, нежный по тембру; противоп. драматический